# python script to search from a list of keywords

Tags: python, bash

I have a list of keywords and I want to build a python script to iterate through each keyword, search (grep?) for against a given file, and write the output to a file.

I know my answer is somewhere in the world of:

```
for words in keywords
grep |word -o foundkeywords.txt
```

Maybe I should stay more in bash? Either way, pardon the noob question and any guidance is very appreciated.

Comment: This is quite broad, and it seems you haven't done your research yet.

Comment: And yet through the magic of the internet my question has been answered! Thanks anyway for the constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash` only:

If you want to `grep` all the keywords at once, you can do

```
grep -f keywords inputfile
```

If you want to `grep` it sequentially, you can do

```
while read line; do
    grep "$line" inputfile
done < keywords
```

Of course, this can be done in Python too. But I don't see how this would facilitate the process.

Answer (score 0):

python does not exactly have a lot to do with bash; that said your script in python should look like this (if there is a word on each line of your keyword file):

```
# open the file
with open('foundkeywords.txt') as f:
    # read each line of the file
    for i in f.read().split('\n'):
        # if the word is find in the line
        # print it
        if i.find(word) != -1:
            print i
```